# HTML2PDF Conversion

Tags: html, windows, pdf

We're developing software for both Linux and Windows that requires CVS files to be generated into PDF reports. I've written a program in C to turn the CVS files into HTML files (td, tr etc.) and am then converting the HTML into PS using html2ps and then ps2pdf under Linux.

However as mentioned above we're also developing for Windows and while I'm aware that html2ps and ps2pdf are available under Windows they have a few dependencies which are going to cause headaches for our clients (namely Perl and Ghostscript). Are there any native Windows console applications that will convert HTML into PDF that can be distributed as single executable files with no major dependencies?

Comment: We used this on a recent project, it has some limitations, but you might want to check it out.
http://www.html-to-pdf.net/Default.aspx?c=g1&gclid=CMGW1pSphJgCFQpuGgodkW4RCg

Comment: Thank you for the link. I probably should've mentioned that we have a limited budget and are quite heavily committed to open source products.

Comment: Your question is off topic on StackOverflow, but you can ask it on the Software Recommendations site, which is also part of the Stack Exchange network. http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

I would like to add a new entry that I've used recently - [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) - it is an open source project that uses webkit to render, which means that it has all the latest and greatest available including CSS3, SVG, and can even let javascript run before creating the pdf. It doesn't have the same level of polish as princeXML, but its the best FOSS solution I've found.

I haven't used it for multi-page documents yet, but I believe it does have support for css page-breaks.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Prince XML](http://www.princexml.com/) with Java and it is extremely powerful and easy to use, but it's also commercial.

Comment: I've used prince as well.  It worked very well for our in-house stuff.  It's output had very good visual parity with the original HTML page.  Shame there isn't an open source equivilent.

Answer (score 2):

I've used ExpertPDF's [Html2Pdf](http://www.html-to-pdf.net/Features.aspx) converter component. Easy to make .NET app to convert.

Answer (score 2):

Check [Pisa](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pisa/). Its completely written in python so should work on Windows and Unix. The license is GPL but commercial license is also available.

Answer (score 1):

I had lots of luck with [HTMLDOC](https://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1).  It is open source and available on many platforms and has a commercial version if you want to pay for it.

Answer (score 1):

We've used [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) in the past to convert XML docs to PDF.  perhaps not quite what you are looking for but It might be an option?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) which has both .NET and Java libraries to use for PDF conversion.  I think it's great to use, but there's definitely a cost involved.

Since you're looking for something open source, I might suggest [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/).  I hear it's good, but haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

[PDFLib](http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-gmbh/) could be bundled with a native application written by yourselves to create PDFs. It's a great library - used to be free but it looks you have to pay for it these days.

Another option, but it doesn't exactly fit your non-dependency requirement, is [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

As Russell says wkhtmltopdf is probably the best bet.  I've created a free online service to convert HTML to PDF files http://www.html2pdfrocket.com which uses wkhtmltopdf but makes the process easy and cross platform.

I've added examples on how to conversion HTML to PDF for PHP, C#, RUBY and HTML.  You could trigger it in JavaScript if you wish.

It's being used by the heart foundation and others to create PDF files in real time, for example PDFs of recipes, invoices, receipts etc - although you can download and cache the PDF output if you wish.

Hope you find it helpful and please write to me there if you have feedback or if you need help getting kwhtmltopdf working in your own env.