# Create PDF file from Text String or HTML String

Tags: codenameone

My **codenameone**-app is producing some data, which I like to be able to summarize in a PDF-file for documentation purposes.

Would it be possible to either use a java library as cn1 library or to use a webservice which converts an HTML String into a PDF file like this:?

https://www.html2pdfrocket.com/convert-android-html-to-pdf

Maybe someone else already figured out a best-practice for this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The HTML or the text you see?

Comment: The text I am collecting from my given data inside the app as String. Could build an HTML String as well.

Comment: Question has already been marked off topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431117/html2pdf-conversion

Comment: This relates to CodenameOne apps ONLY.

Comment: I had https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ in mind, but than I saw that is for CodeNameOne, I am not sure if it works for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no current builtin solution for that, it should be easy enough to wrap native libs or maybe even port a JavaSE lib that does that. Most of the developers who do something like this use a server side process to generate the PDF.

Comment: Your right, a server side process is, at least in my case, the simplest way. Nice work with the Util.downloadUrlTo*-methods!

Answer (score 0):

After giving it a quick-and-dirty try with *html2pdfrocket* - instead of using or porting a java library - I was simply **amazed** by the simplicity of the possibility with codenameone. I wasn't expecting this to be so easy AT ALL.

This class and method is all you'd need to simply save the pdf file to FileSystemStorage.

```
import com.codename1.io.Util;

public class PDFHandler {

private final static String URL="http://api.html2pdfrocket.com/pdf";
private final static String APIKEY = "<YOURAPI-KEY>";


/**
 * Stores given HTML String or URL to Storage with given filename
 * @param value URL or HTML add quote if you have spaces. use single quotes instead of double
 * @param filename
 */
public void getFile(String value,String filename){
    // Validate parameters
    if(value==null||value.length()<1) 
        return;
    if(filename==null||filename.length()<1)
        return;
    //Encode
    value = Util.encodeUrl(value);

    String fullPathToFile = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath()+filename;
    Util.downloadUrlToFileSystemInBackground(URL+"?apikey="+APIKEY+"&value="+value, fullPathToFile);
}

}
```

I hope this helps some other codenameone-newbie!